Build GMP from source on an intel celeron J4125 : (not so) strange issues with libtool
(Long story short.)
I have a synology DS920+ (equipped with an intel celeron J4125 CPU.) I need a fortran compiler on it to compile and use a very-legacy tool.
I therefore naturally installed Entware (a side command-line package manager) knowing that it provides the package gcc, package which usually contains, among C and C++ compilers and other compilers linkers etc, the GCC's fortran compiler gfortran. (I used the "recommended" installation type from Entware's github and installed all recommanded packages, which are btw always the needed packages for any platform you want to build GCC from source on.)
But sadly that package provides only GCC's C and C++ compilers. Positive point though : these C and C++ compilers are still enough to build the full GCC from source, including the fortran compiler gfortran. (I did that several times already on various nix platforms, often because I wanted to have GCC with ISL, CLOOG optimizations.)
To build GCC from source I need to build GMP first, so that I did :
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-6.3.0.tar.xz
tar -Jxf gmp-6.3.0.tar.xz
cd gmp-6.3.0/
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0 --enable-cxx
make

The make yields the error :
./libtool: line 2642: func__fatal_error: command not found

That's a huge typo as it should be func_fatal_error instead of func__fatal_error. No worries : I sudo nano'd the libtool file and made the change, and re-"make'd", to finally have the following error, the real serious error  :
libtool:   error: unsupported hardcode properties See the libtool documentation for more information. Fatal configuration error.

triggered by (the execution of) the command :
./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8   -version-info 11:0:7  -o libgmpxx.la -rpath /usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.3.0/lib cxx/dummy.lo cxx/isfuns.lo cxx/ismpf.lo cxx/ismpq.lo cxx/ismpz.lo cxx/ismpznw.lo cxx/limits.lo cxx/osdoprnti.lo cxx/osfuns.lo cxx/osmpf.lo cxx/osmpq.lo cxx/osmpz.lo libgmp.la

This leaves me helpless as I am not at all (least to say) a libtool expert, even more knowing that a quick search about the error globally tells that error indeed comes from libtool and is not very helpful as it does not at all indicate what's really going on, and that it is triggered in a lot a different contexts across libtool's use, with a lot of different causes.
Here is the gist of the libtool file (after the _ correction of course). (I could provide more "output" infos through gists if needed.)
Help would be very much appreciated.
